# Creating a list

Tags: c, linked-list

A  function reads an input ﬁle containing positive integers (one number per line) and creates a list containing these numbers, one per cell. -1 in the input ﬁle indicates end of the list. This way you can have multiple lists speciﬁed in the same input ﬁle. Assume that the input ﬁle is called “input”. Each call to a function  reads the numbers in the input ﬁle, until -1 is reached, and puts these numbers in the list, and returns a pointer to the head of this list. Thus, if the input ﬁle contains
1 5 4 -1 4 8 6 -1 -1 7 8
Then ﬁrst call to function will return a pointer to the list 1->5->4->null and the second call to a function  will return a pointer to the list 4->8->6->null.
Third call will return null and 4th call will return 7->8-> null. I wanted to achieve this , So far I am able to read the file from the text file. Now I wanted for each -1 encountered fin file it should take the number until that -1 and create a list .

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list {
    char *string;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list LIST;

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128];
    LIST *current, *head;

    head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        LIST *node = (struct list * )malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->string = _strdup(line);// strdup(line);//note : strdup is not standard function
        node->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            current = head = node;
        }
        else {
            current = current->next = node;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //test print
    for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
        printf("%s", current->string);
    }
    //need free for each node
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question in there.

Comment: There a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Does each list store to list of list?

Comment: No, it should simply print the list , in this case as u see from the sample input , it should create 4 list , as explained in the example.

Comment: I am new in Using c as well as in using StackOverflow , If there is some misconception in understanding the question / formatting, kindly add a comment /suggestion and I will make necessary changes before down voting.

Comment: @AppCode To be clear, the post does not ask a question.  Lacking that, makes it more difficult for answers to apply to the post.  There is no misconception in understanding the question as there is no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int v;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list LIST;

LIST *makeListFromFile(FILE *fp){
    int v;
    LIST *current, *head = NULL;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &v) == 1 && v != -1){
        LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->v = v;
        node->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            current = head = node;
        else
            current = current->next = node;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        LIST *list = makeListFromFile(fp);
        while(list){
            LIST *temp = list->next;
            printf("%d ", list->v);
            free(list);
            list = temp;
        }
        puts("NULL");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```